# autokrige and proj4string

Tags: r, spatial-interpolation, automap

I am using the R function `autokrige` from `automap` package, but I got an error and I do not know how to solve it. Do you have any hints?

Thank you!

```
sp.poidf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp.poi,thresh.df)
proj4string(sp.poidf) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
pro.df=spTransform(sp.poidf, CRS("+proj=merc +zone=32s +datum=WGS84"))
sp.new <- SpatialPoints(new.poi)
proj4string(sp.new) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
pro.new <- spTransform(sp.new, CRS("+proj=merc +zone=32s +datum=WGS84"))
mykri <- autoKrige(mythresh~1,pro.df,newdata=pro.new)

Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function "proj4string", for signature "NULL"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code reproduces your problem:

```
require(automap)
require(rgdal)
loadMeuse()

proj4string(meuse) = CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
proj4string(meuse.grid) = CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
meuse = spTransform(meuse, CRS("+proj=merc +zone=32s +datum=WGS84"))
# Note that meuse.grid no longer is a grid due to the reprojection
meuse.grid = spTransform(meuse.grid, CRS("+proj=merc +zone=32s +datum=WGS84"))

kr = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, newdata = meuse.grid)
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "proj4string", for signature "NULL"
```

The problem is that you use `newdata =`, while you should be using `new_data =` (note the underscore). The following code runs fine:

```
kr = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, new_data = meuse.grid)
```

The documentation of `autoKrige` shows this, but `krige` (from gstat) uses `newdata`, so I understand the confusion.

What goes wrong is that `newdata =` is not recognized by `autoKrige`, and put in the `...` part of the argument list. When `autoKrige` calls `krige` there is a conflict between `new_data` supplied by `autoKrige`, and `newdata` supplied via `...`. To prevent other users from ending up with the rather vague error message, I added a check to automap. The erroneous code now leads to an exception:

```
> kr = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, newdata = meuse.grid)
Error in autoKrige(zinc ~ 1, meuse, newdata = meuse.grid) : 
  The argument name for the prediction object is not 'newdata', but 'new_data'.
```

Comment: The new version will be on CRAN soon.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the widely accepted standard argument name of `newdata` for this sort of thing? Inconsistencies don't help R's learning curve.